# Как получить абсолютный путь к файлам?

Tags: android, java

Понятное дело, можно сделать так:

```
File imgFile = context.getFileStreamPath("vasya.png");
Log.i("LOG s",imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Но можно ли получить без объявления переменной File? И сразу второй вопрос - File переменная много ли памяти кушает? Или это только указатель?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это класс, который обращается к файловой системе или к таблице файлов файловой систем. В себя он ничего не считывает, поэтому можно особо не бояться его создавать. Вот если вы откроете поток, тогда да, будет долго.